# Error CSRF token not Found , Laravel DataTable Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatables

En mi proyecto con Laravel estoy tratando de implementar notificaciones en tiempo real para una ordenes de trabajo. Estoy utilizando pusher y vue.js.
Al momento de agregar mi script compilado por laravel-mix("simplemente lo utilice para crear mi componente notificaciones")

->Archivo app.blade.php: (script)

```
@stack('scripts')

<!-- AdminLTE App -->

<script src="/adminlte/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Tengo el siguiente problema **CSRF token not found** (adjunto imagen):

[image: LISTADO ORDENES]

->Mi datatables no carga la información del listado de todas las ordenes de trabajo.

->En la consola aparece el siguiente error:

```
app.js:59101 CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token
```

->Lo raro es que si tengo asignado el csrf-token en mi archivo app.blade.php

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

y por otro lado la extencion de chrome vue Devtools si reconoce mi template

Alcaro lo siguiente con el @stack('scripts') cargo los script de mi datatables y otros mas que se encuentran en mi vista index:

->Index.blade.php

```
@push('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="{{ asset('js/order.js') }}"></script>


    <script>
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('orders.table') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'n°_orden', name: 'n°_orden'},
                {data: 'fecha', name: 'fecha'},
                {data: 'cliente', name: 'cliente'},
                {data: 'operario', name: 'operario'},
                {data: 'producto', name: 'producto'},
                {data: 'estado', name: 'estado'},               
                {data: 'accion', name: 'accion'}                
            ]
        }); 


    </script>
@endpush
```

->Laravel-mix: (archivo a compilar)

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

// mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
//    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js(['resources/js/app.js'], 'public/js/app.js');
```

Realice 2 pruebas:

Prueba 1)
Si saco dicho script de mi archivo app.blade.php, mi datatables si lista todas las ordenes de trabajos registradas, pero vue Devtools no reconoce mi template.

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Prueba 2)

Si en mi archivo bootstrap.js comento el let token que viene por defecto y agrego el de abajo, compilo y luego vuelvo a inspeccionar el navegador note que el error de `CSRF token not found`, desaparece pero mi datatables sigue sin cargar la información.

```
//let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
```

Si en realidad funcionaria me tendría que listar todas las ordenes de trabajo sin algún tipo de problemas y mostrar la "campanita de notificaciones".

No entiendo porque me muestra ese error.

**ACTUALIZADO**

Realice otro tipo de inspeccion. Para comprobar que mi script order.js carga correctamente añadi como primer linea en mi archivo un console.log.

```
console.log('el archivo orders.js carga');
```

revisando en el navegador veo dicho mensaje pero mi datatables no lista ninguna orden:

este es el script order.js

```
console.log('el archivo orders.js carga');

$('body').on('click', '.modal-show', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this),
        url = me.attr('href'),
        title = me.attr('title');     

    $('#modal-title').text(title);
    $('#modal-btn-save').removeClass('hide')
    .text(me.hasClass('edit') ? 'Actualizar' : 'Crear');   


    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#modal-body').html(response);          

            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                language: 'es'
            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());                  

            var name_companySelect = $('#name_company');
            var phone_company = $('#phone_company');
            var name_client = $('#name_client');
            var phone_client = $('#phone_client');
            var email = $('#email');            
            var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');    
            // console.log (name_companySelect);
            name_companySelect.on('change', function() {
                // console.log ('la compañía ha cambiado');
                var id = $(this).val();
                // console.log('id del Company seleccionado: ' + id);
                obtenerDetalleDeCompany(id)

            });            

            function obtenerDetalleDeCompany(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    // url: 'companies/' + id,
                    url: '/admin/orders/' + id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {            
                        '_token': csrf_token
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // acá podés loguear la respuesta del servidor
                        console.log(response);
                        // le pasás la data a la función que llena los otros inputs
                        llenarInputs(response);
                    },
                    error: function () { 
                        console.log(error);
                        alert('Hubo un error obteniendo el detalle de la Compañía!');
                    }
                })
            }

            function llenarInputs(data) {
                // $clientes->company['phone_company']
                phone_company.val(data.company.phone_company);  
                name_client.val(data.name_client);    
                phone_client.val(data.phone_client);    
                email.val(data.email);    
            }           
        }
    }); 

    $('#modal').modal('show');      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder al valor del `token` asociado a su etiqueta  meta, debe acceder por medio del atributo content.

```
let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
```

Si realiza peticiones con JQuery, la configuración para el `token` sería utilizando [$.ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), *(ejm)*

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
});
```

Comment: con lo que me indicaste el error de  CSRF token not found no aparecio mas. Por otro lado sigo sin poder cargar el listado de todas las ordenes en mi datatables

Comment: Verifique en consola si tiene algún error, o en el request desde el navegador. Hay más de 1 razón posible por la cuál no le carga el dt.

Comment: vuelvo a la misma conclusion si comento el script compilado con laravel-mix de mi plantilla app.blade.php, toda la app funciona sin problemas. Ahora como prueba fue agregar nuevamente el script y volver a compilar con npm run dev, voy al navegador  y se listan las todas la ordenes sin problemas, pero si vuelvo a recargar la pagina no responde, no realizo ninguna accion despues de unos minutos vuelvo a recargar y me listan las ordenes en el datatables

Comment: no estoy seguro pero para mi tiene algo que ver con la llamada ajax ya que uso respuesta del lado del servidor. Lo vuelvo a confirmar no me aparecen errores en la consola del navegador simplemente demora algunos minutos en cargar la informacion a que se debe esto? tendria que pasar y compilar todos mis js y css con laravel-mix?